# Retrieved Data from Firebasedatabase and set into recyclierview Adapter

Tags: android

I want to read the data from firebasedatabase and show that into recyclerview retrieve data form FirebaseDatabase by orderbychild method. I want to read data of that child who's email match with my useremail who is currently login from app .

This is my Firebase:

[image]

I have successfully completed the first part, but I am facing problems with second part how can I pass the retrieved data to recyclerview adapter.

For example whenever user login from `mobeen@gmail.com` I read his location and ticket_no and show that data into recyclerview. I am facing problem with this line

```
programinglist.setAdapter(new myadapter(this,  modl1));
```

where should I pass my modl1 (`ArrayList<model> modl1`) to `recyclerview.setadapter`

```
public class recyclierview extends AppCompatActivity {
public  RecyclerView programinglist;
    DatabaseReference b1, b2;
    public ArrayList<model> modl1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recyclierview);
          programinglist = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        programinglist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        modl1  =new ArrayList<model>();
      readdata(new firebasecallback() {
          @Override
          public void oncallback(ArrayList<model> list) {
              Log.v("aliraza" , "value oncalback" + list.get(0).getTicket_no());
          }
      });
}  

 private  void readdata(final firebasecallback firebasecallback)
    {
        b1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        b2=b1.child("tasks");
        b2.orderByChild("email").equalTo(MainActivity.email).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


                model m = new model();
                String location = dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue().toString();
                String tickeno = dataSnapshot.child("ticket_no").getValue().toString();
                Log.v("ALI", "family value " +location);
                Log.v("ALI", "family value " + tickeno);
                m.setLocation(location);
                Log.v("ALI", "location " +m.getLocation());
                m.setTicket_no(tickeno);
                modl1.add(m);
                Log.v("ALI", "family value " +modl1.get(0).getTicket_no());
                firebasecallback.oncallback(modl1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        programinglist.setAdapter(new myadapter(this,  modl1));// where should i call this setadapter function of recyclierview.enter code here



    }
    private  interface firebasecallback
    {
        void oncallback( ArrayList<model> list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise your arraylist and adapter;

```
 public ArrayList<model> modl1=new ArrayList();
 private myadapter adapter;
```

In **onCreate()** method initialize your adapter with blank list and set adapter to recyclerview.

```
adapter=new myadapter(this,  modl1);
programinglist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then create a method **addItem()** in your adapter.

```
public void addItem(model item){
   list.add(item); // add item to your adapter list
   notifyItemInserted(list.size());
 }
```

changes in onChildAdded() method

```
modl1.add(m); //remove this line 
 firebasecallback.oncallback(m);

 readdata(new firebasecallback() {
          @Override
          public void oncallback(model m) {
          modl1.add(m);
          adapter.add(m);
              Log.v("aliraza" , "value oncalback" + list.get(0).getTicket_no());

          }
      });
```

You can remove firebasecallback method,as there is no need of it, and directly add item to adapter in onChildAdded() method. Simply call **readdata()** method from **onCreate()**

```
private  void readdata()
    {
        b1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        b2=b1.child("tasks");
        b2.orderByChild("email").equalTo(MainActivity.email).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


                model m = new model();
                String location = dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue().toString();
                String tickeno = dataSnapshot.child("ticket_no").getValue().toString();
                Log.v("ALI", "family value " +location);
                Log.v("ALI", "family value " + tickeno);
                m.setLocation(location);
                Log.v("ALI", "location " +m.getLocation());
                m.setTicket_no(tickeno);
                modl1.add(m);
                Log.v("ALI", "family value " +modl1.get(0).getTicket_no());
                adapter.add(m);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




    }
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: yes, in that callback you have to make change for object, otherwise duplication will occur in adapter. or you can directly use  adapter.add(m); in childAdded() method without using callback

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in my question mam . Mam should i write this line  firebasecallback.oncallback(m);
in childadded(); because m is the object of the class and oncallback() function recived arraylist . please heave a look on that part of my code  private  interface firebasecallback
    {
        void oncallback( ArrayList<model> list);
    }         we must pass an arraylist of model class to oncallback()  fun not the object of the model class

Comment: Yes, please check I have already modified your code their also. or you can use as I suggested above without callback.

Comment: and the second thing is when is call readdata function in childadded()  instead of  in oncreate() . i am getting an error on firebasecallback() which is  (class anonymous class derived from firebasecalbackl must either be decleared abstract or implement abstract method on callback in firebasecallback()) .

Comment: Mam i am using callback method because  android take a few milli second to read data from  firebase . so when i execute this line   programinglist.setAdapter(new myadapter(this, modl1)); of the code without firebasecallback it execute before this line    m.setLocation(location);  and as a result modl1 is empty thats why i am using firebasecallback method bcz i want to first read the data from firebase and then put data into programinglist.setaddapter() method

Comment: Mam thank laot .Its working for me thank you so much mam ...from last days 2 days i was not able to solve that problem thanks alot mam ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207237/discussion-between-ali-raza-and-nehal-godhasara).